# Google static Maps API - create image with 1000's of points

Tags: java, google-maps

I'd like to generate a static google map with several thousand points plotted.

Static maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

The url format will hit the URL length restriction REAL quick. So that won't work. Any way to send in an XML document or something that has all the points?

Can that be done?

My main desire is to get an Image file that I can use in a PDF report. But I don't know how to generate an image from the dyanmic report on the **server side**. The beauty of the static maps api is i can generate the image from the web server.

Any solutions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a way for you to send an accompanying file with a static maps request though it may exist.

Is it possible for you to use dynamic maps? The javascript API is easy to pickup and makes it very simple to add markers/ points on the map. From my experience, this will allow you to add as many points as you like but may become a big laggy when getting into the 1000's.

Comment: I know that's what the examples all show, but i want it to be an image that I can include in a PDF report kind of thing.

Comment: Still gave you +1 because I should have stated that the dynamic api won't work for me.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?